# Validate date in both 'mm-dd-yyyy' and 'mm/dd/yyyy' formats using JQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, jquery-ui

Validate date in both  'mm-dd-yyyy' and 'mm/dd/yyyy'  formats using JQuery Validate.

I have tried with this code with one format, however, the my code (shown in the following) will not work for both 'mm-dd-yyyy' and 'mm/dd/yyyy' formats.
My Code :

```
$(document).on('blur','.dateValidation',function(){ 

            var input=$(this).val();
            var r = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
            if(!r.test(input)) {
              alert("Invalid Input");
              return;
            }
            var a = input.match(r), d = new Date(a[3],a[1] - 1,a[2]);
            if(d.getFullYear() != a[3] || d.getMonth() + 1 != a[1] || d.getDate() != a[2]) {
              alert("Invalid Date");
              return;

            } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put in an array the date formats that you support and loop on that. For example with a function like this:

```
function isValidDate(input) {
  var regexes = [
    /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/,
    /^(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{4})$/
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < regexes.length; i++) {
    var r = regexes[i];
    if(!r.test(input)) {
      continue;
    }
    var a = input.match(r), d = new Date(a[3],a[1] - 1,a[2]);
    if(d.getFullYear() != a[3] || d.getMonth() + 1 != a[1] || d.getDate() != a[2]) {
      continue;
    }
    // All checks passed:
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Then you call it from your code like so:

```
$(document).on('blur','.dateValidation',function(){ 
  var isValid = isValidDate($(this).val());
  if (isValid) {
    alert('Valid date');
  } else {
    alert('Invalid date');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check against two regexs which I suspect you may have been trying to avoid.

```
    var input=$(this).val();
    var r1 = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/;
    var r2 = /^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/;

    var a;
    if (r1.test(input)) {
      a = input.match(r1);
    } else if (r2.test(input) {
      a = input.match(r2);
    } else {
      alert("Invalid Input");
      return;
    }

    var d = new Date(a[3],a[1] - 1,a[2]);
    if (d.getFullYear() != a[3] || 
        d.getMonth() + 1 != a[1] || 
        d.getDate() != a[2]) {
      alert("Invalid Date");
      return;
    }
```

If you are open to using an external js library.  I would use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/).

```
var d = moment($(this).val(), ["D-M-YYYY", "D/M/YYYY"], true); 
if(d == null || !d.isValid()) {
    alert('Invalid Date');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't worry about treating mixed delimiters (e.g. dd-mm/yyyy) as valid, then the simplest way may be to use `[\-\/]` instead of `\/` in your regex:

```
var r = /^(\d{1,2})[\-\/](\d{1,2})[\-\/](\d{4})$/;
```